# How to combine the numbers of an input field and an option from a drop down selection in order to solve an equation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am building a [picture framing matting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat_(picture_framing)) calculator.  The problem I'm having is that I have an `<input type="number">` and a `<select>` with `<option value>` elements that need to be combined to calculate an equation.  The two fields, say I input 16 and I use the drop down menu (next to that input field) to select 1/4, to form 16 1/4 - the 1/4 is not being combined with the 16 when the "Calculate" button is pressed to solve the equation.

Here is my code snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}


/*Fieldset and legend */

fieldset {
  margin: 2em 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  min-width: P 200px;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 .25em;
  color: #999;
}


/* Labels */

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.checks label {
  margin-top: 0;
}

label:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/* Select */

select {
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#wff, #hff, #wpf, #hpf {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;

  }
  
  body {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2em;
  }


/* Inputs and textarea */

input {
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  background-color: #D3D3D3
}

input[type="number"],
input[type="text"] {
  width: 10em;
  background-color: #D3D3D3
}

textarea {
  min-height: 8em;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  background-color: #D3D3D3
}


/* radio buttons and checkboxes */

.checks {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.checks p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label,
input[type="radio"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#height {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}


/* Submit Button */

input[type="button"] {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
}


/* Large screen rules */

@media screen and (min-width: 430px) {
  legend {
    font-size: 1.75em;
  }
  fieldset {
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .checks label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: .5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
    
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name "viewport" content="width=device-width,

        initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>I Was Framed - Calculator</title>



        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>

<body>

<section>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">

<fieldset>

<legend>

I Was Framed Calculator

</legend>



<label for="frameWidth">Frame Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wf" id="wf" required><select name="wff" id="wff" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option> 
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>

<label for="frameHeight">Frame Height:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hf" id="hf" required><select name="hff" id="hff" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>



<label for="pictureWidth">Picture Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wp" id="wp" required><select name="wpf" id="wpf" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>

<label for="pictureHeight">Picture Height:</label><input type="number"onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hp" id="hp" required><select name="hpf" id="hpf" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select><br>

<label for="matOverlap">Mat Overlap:</label><select name="o" id="o" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>

    <br>


<br>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc"/>

</fieldset>

</form>

</section>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fractional@1.0.0/index.js"></script>

<script>

function calc()

{

    var wf = document.getElementById('wf').value
    
    var hf = document.getElementById('hf').value
    
    var wp = document.getElementById('wp').value
    
    var hp = document.getElementById('hp').value
    
    var o = document.getElementById('o').value
    
   var width = (1/2)*(hf-hp+o);
   var height = (1/2)*(wf-wp+o);

   document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = new Fraction(width).toString();
   document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = new Fraction(height).toString();

   document.getElementById('rectangle').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'})

}

</script>


<center>
    <div style="width:75%;height:0;border:5px solid #000; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;padding-bottom:75%;background-color:gray" id="rectangle">
        <center>
            <div id="width"></div>
        </center>
   
        <div id="height"></div>
    </div>
</center>


</body>

</html>
```

---

### What I've tried

1. I've attempted to set the both the id's the same in an effort to add them together.
2. As one id example, I've added:  `var wff = document.getElementById('wff').value` to my code, then changed my formula to:  `var height = (1/2)*(wf+wff-wp+o);`

Both attempts did not work, so I need direction how to combine the numbers of the input & the drop down selection, so I can add it to my equation.

---

Here are two images reflecting the issue:

1. [image: Image shows calculator getting correct answer when NOT using side-by-side drop down selections].
2. [image: Image shows when a drop down menu is used - the calculation results into the same answer as above (which in this case would be a wrong answer because the fraction wasn't taken into account.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change `string` to the `interger` or `float` by using `parseFloat` and `parseInt`
I have added the solution for this. Below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}


/*Fieldset and legend */

fieldset {
  margin: 2em 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  min-width: P 200px;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 .25em;
  color: #999;
}


/* Labels */

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.checks label {
  margin-top: 0;
}

label:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/* Select */

select {
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#wff, #hff, #wpf, #hpf {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;

  }
  
  body {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2em;
  }


/* Inputs and textarea */

input {
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  background-color: #D3D3D3
}

input[type="number"],
input[type="text"] {
  width: 10em;
  background-color: #D3D3D3
}

textarea {
  min-height: 8em;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  background-color: #D3D3D3
}


/* radio buttons and checkboxes */

.checks {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.checks p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label,
input[type="radio"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#height {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}


/* Submit Button */

input[type="button"] {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
}


/* Large screen rules */

@media screen and (min-width: 430px) {
  legend {
    font-size: 1.75em;
  }
  fieldset {
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .checks label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: .5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
    
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name "viewport" content="width=device-width,

        initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>I Was Framed - Calculator</title>



        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>

<body>

<section>

<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">

<fieldset>

<legend>

I Was Framed Calculator

</legend>



<label for="frameWidth">Frame Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wf" id="wf" required><select name="wff" id="wff" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option> 
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>

<label for="frameHeight">Frame Height:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hf" id="hf" required><select name="hff" id="hff" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>



<label for="pictureWidth">Picture Width:</label><input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="wp" id="wp" required><select name="wpf" id="wpf" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>

<label for="pictureHeight">Picture Height:</label><input type="number"onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="hp" id="hp" required><select name="hpf" id="hpf" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select><br>

<label for="matOverlap">Mat Overlap:</label><select name="o" id="o" required>
    <option value="none" selected="selected"> -- choose one --</option>
    <option value=".0">0</option>
        <option value=".0625">1/16</option>
            <option value=".0125">1/8</option>
                <option value=".1875">3/16</option>
                <option value=".25">1/4</option>
                <option value=".3125">5/16</option>
                <option value=".375">3/8</option>
                <option value=".4375">7/16</option>
                <option value=".50">1/2</option>
                <option value=".5625">9/16</option>
                <option value=".625">5/8</option>
                <option value=".6875">11/16</option>
                <option value=".75">3/4</option>
                <option value=".8125">3/16</option>
                <option value=".875">7/8</option>
                <option value=".9375">15/16</option>
</select>

    <br>


<br>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc"/>

</fieldset>

</form>

</section>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fractional@1.0.0/index.js"></script>

<script>

function calc()

{

    var wf = document.getElementById('wf').value
    wf = parseInt(wf)

    var wff = document.getElementById('wff').value
    wff = parseInt(wff)
    
    var hf = document.getElementById('hf').value
    hf = parseInt(hf)

    var hff = document.getElementById('hff').value
    hff = parseInt(hff)
    
    var wp = document.getElementById('wp').value
    wp = parseInt(wp)

    var wpf = document.getElementById('wpf').value
    wpf = parseInt(wpf)
    
    var hp = document.getElementById('hp').value
    hp = parseInt(hp)

    var hpf = document.getElementById('hpf').value
    hpf = parseInt(hpf)
    
    var o = document.getElementById('o').value
    o = parseFloat(o)
   var width = (1/2)*(hf-hp+o);
   var height = (1/2)*(wf-wp+o);

   document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = new Fraction(width).toString();
   document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = new Fraction(height).toString();

   document.getElementById('rectangle').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'})

}

</script>


<center>
    <div style="width:75%;height:0;border:5px solid #000; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;padding-bottom:75%;background-color:gray" id="rectangle">
        <center>
            <div id="width"></div>
        </center>
   
        <div id="height"></div>
    </div>
</center>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing some guidance.  But, if you could help me to understand.  I ran your code snippet and from my end it's still doing the exact same thing as before.  Am I needing to change something else aside from what you already added?  I edited my original post to include images of what still happening now.

Comment: @Sanders you need to get the values of the select fields as you get the values of single input, then convert it to the `string` to `interger`, after this add these values

Comment: `var width = (1/2)*(hf-hp+o);
   var height = (1/2)*(wf-wp+o);
` in this you added only inputs values

Comment: This is perfect; makes perfect sense.  So, regarding the equations:  if I need to combine the input field with its respective drop down selection, then do I simply add(+) them together in the equation.  In other words, `var width = (1/2)*((hf+hff)-(hp+hpf)+o);` and `var height = (1/2)*((wf+wff)-(wp+wpf)+o);`?  Because I'm receiving the same error for both `width` & `height`.  The error is:  `NaN NaN/1`.  Am I not structuring the equation correctly?

Comment: @Sanders you received `NaN`  because you added `integer` to the `string` that's why i change it to the `parseInt` to make it `integer/number`. 
If you still receive `NaN` then the possible error is that when you divide `1/16` or else it gives the value in `.0625` and you need to add it like `0.0625`

Comment: I changed the drop down options to reflect the `0` before the decimals such as the `.0625` to `0.0625`.  And I made sure my equations include the input values and drop down menu options.  All results to `NaN`.  Can you check my JSFiddle, please? 
 [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zm35kn6y/).  

Also on a side note, if I enter the old equations:  `var width = (1/2)*(hf-hp+o);` and `var height = (1/2)*(wf-wp+o);` then the result is `NaN`  unless I select a `Mat Overlap` option.

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine!

Comment: you just need to remove ` -- choose one --` or you can set its value to zero `0`

Comment: Here's my new fiddle with those changes:  https://jsfiddle.net/kgdvsaeu/1/ and it works perfectly!!!  Thank you for everything!!